# After logout with one user, then loggin with another user, old user information persist, need to refresh. Angular 8 and Firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

first time I post on stack overflow, I hope everything will be fine with my request.

So there is my problem.

I'm using Firestore vanilla SDK in an Angular 8.0 project in order to retrieve information from database (so I'm working with onSnapshot(docSnapshot) function and I'm using unsubcribe function in `ngOnDestroy()`).

```js
  private unsubUser : () => void = () => {};

  actualUser : User;

  constructor(private userService : UserService, private formBuilder : FormBuilder, private storageService : StorageService) {}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.initForm();
    this.unsubUser = this.userService.getActualUser().onSnapshot((doc) => {
      this.actualUser = doc.data() as User;
      this.initFormAfterData();
    }) 
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.unsubUser();
  }
```

If I decide to logout with this logged in user, i'll be redirect to the auth page, everything is ok so far.

Now, I decide to log in with another account.

But I'm currently retrieving previous logged in user information , like if the old firebase connection was still there. I need to perform this :

```
window.location.reload();
```

in the signOut() function

```js
signOut(){
    firebase.auth().signOut()
    localStorage.clear();
    sessionStorage.clear();
    window.location.reload();
}
```

to reset the previous connection on the logout function...

Did someone encounter this problem once ?

Comment: are you use form to retain data

Comment: Hello, nop i'm only using form to send values to firestore.

Comment: Please have a look at [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As it stands, we have no way of knowing what `this.userService.getActualUser()` does, and it's also hard to understand the flow between the various snippets you shared.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct. Since you are using firebase authentication you need to call `signOut()` to sign out the current user. Therefore, when you log in with a different user and you use `user.displayName` you will be able to obtain the name of the newly logged in user.

Regarding `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` it depends what you are storing, if you have `localStorage.setItem('email', "currentLoginEmail@gmail.com");`, then yes you need to clear that also on sign out.

Comment: Hello, first of all thanks for your answer ! I don't store anything in the localStorage or the sessionStorage object but i thought it could help me in my problem. I don't understand why I receive the old authenticated user information when i log in with a new user... This is a very strange behaviour and I need to reload the page in order to reset all the previous connection with firebase...

Comment: you have to call `firebase.auth().signOut()` and your problem will be solved

Comment: Yes this is what I do.. I don't understand where this problem come from.. I keep searching in my code. Thanks for helping me !

Answer (score 0):

For those who encounter the same problem.
It was my fault.

In fact, in my user service, I was initializing only one time in a private var the uid that I re use on my other functions

I just cleaned it by instantiate in every function the

uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid